# Bug in Tag-Stat Rendering

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, design, top-users

I just noticed that the stats page is rendering improperly for tags that cary large enough statistics (char length). For instance, if you view the stats for [R](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/stats)
 you will see two columns floated left. If you view the stats for [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/stats) the columns are a bit too wide, breaking the float-effect, and stacking the columns rather than placing them side-by-side.

[image]

*(sorry, no freehand circles)*

Comment: Too much gloss, not enough freehand circles. You haven't been that long away from Meta Sampson.

Comment: -1 for soulless image!

Comment: Tearing down my reputation because I didn't include freehand circles?

Comment: Whoa! Wild CSS bug - how do i get that skewed-reflection bug on *my* pages??

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: yes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a dupe, I've seen that before. I think it had more freehand circles and less gloss.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that the display of "total score" in the stats page should be adjusted to follow suit with the way reputation is handled near a user's avatar.

Anything over 10,000 is displayed as 10K, 10.1K, etc. Also instead of displaying just the text "total score" in the `title` attribute on those items, show the detailed score:

```
<span class="top-count" style="color:#ccc" title="total score: 19,496">19.5K</span>
```

This would keep the columns from wrapping, but still retain the level of detail displayed before.

Comment: +550 Simple, and consistent with the rest of the site.

Answer (score 4):

Solution: Change *Last 30 Days* and *All time* divs to `width: 46%`.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed in dev, I set the width.

Comment: which caused this issue... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63867/jon-skeets-broken-the-c-tag-stats-page-formatting-on-so