# One Hundred Paper Cuts - An UI Improvement User Style

Tags: discussion, user-interface, design

I've been keeping this to myself for a little too long... its a fairly long user script that attempts to fix some of the UI bugs on Stack Overflow, as well as a few minor enhancements. Enhancements are of course always subjective, so if you dislike any of them, simply rip them out from the code. It is well commented, and split into many sub-sections, and should be easy enough to work with if you want.

One word of advice before using this style: Although most enhancements are minor the style does decreases global font size. This is partly because when developing the style I did not notice I was using an [unsupported font size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61780/stackoverflow-blog-layout-problem), and so has to do this in order to not break this for the other 99% of SO users.

Here's a partial list of bug fixes/feature request from Meta:

- [Move the remove tag “X” icon inside the tag in interesting/ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-x-icon-inside-the-tag-in-interesting-ignored-tags)
- [Bug in Tag-Stat Rendering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36049/bug-in-tag-stat-rendering)
- [In question lists, some of the question body previews wrap strangely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4545/in-question-lists-some-of-the-question-body-previews-wrap-strangely)

And enhancements:

- Two columns for latest tag on homepage, with minor squeezing needed for the occasional long tag (Does not work very well on Chrome so far)
- Made badges smaller, removed sponsored tag logos
- Shifted vote boxes on homepage inwards to add some padding for interesting question highlighting
- Moved Featured Question bounty to the right
- Added border to interested question's vote box to improve contrast between grey vote count and yellow background
- Adjusted answer editor width to match that of elements above it
- 10k tools links now uses the entire list item as hit area for link
- Fixed up some `/review` and `/tools` CSS problems

You can install and see the code here:

> #### http://userstyles.org/styles/35963

Now I just need you folks to give it a spin and drop some comments. :)

Comment: Is there anything I can do about it flashing the page with default styles first, and then switching to the new style?

Comment: @jjnguy: Depends on installation method, I think. Greasemonkey scripts usually takes a second to kick in, but I don't think I've ever had that problem with Stylish

Comment: I installed it in chrome using stylish.  Hmm...

Comment: Besides that, I like it, but the flashing is making it unusable for me.

Comment: Need to fix "cross-site tag sets>>" displaying over "Favorite Tags" underbar

Comment: Shouldn't this be called "one hundred bandaids"? :)

Comment: I've just updated this thingadongdong with all the fixes I've made to it since Auguest. I can't believe there are actually people using this, huh.

Comment: 2 mins after that last update, balpha pushed an update to the 10k tools -_-"

Comment: @YiJiang - That's our Balpha!

Comment: It would be a bit of work but it would be nice showing before and after screenshots of the changes.

Comment: @Pollyanna Too many stuff, heh. The style is designed to make minor adjustments to lots of stuff (hence the name) but I can try to take screenshots of the major changes

Comment: There's a ["Scripts" section over at StackApps](http://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts) where you can list your user-style, should you desire.

Comment: @JaredHarley I know about the script section, but this isn't a script per se, it's just a lot of userstyle

Answer (score 1):

- add `p.ar { display: none !important;}` to suppress "Cross Site Tags"
- add `#custom-header { display: none !important}` to get rid of background bar we don't need