# Jon Skeet's broken the C# tag stats page formatting on SO!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-users

See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers

> [image]

Comment: (Couldn't resist the title, apologies to Jon.)

Comment: Nothing but trouble, that guy.

Comment: Yeah, you give a guy a picture of a unicorn and *this* is how he repays you.

Comment: The disturbing thing is that he has only answered approx 5.04828% of the All Time c# questions, and 4.86025% over the last 30 days. Not only is his average dropping, he has let 95% of the questions slip by as he does Other Things (like sleeping?).

Comment: @Andy E although... Looking at that painting, this could be rightful revenge. Just sayin'... It's not really suitable for the living room wall :D (not that it was intended to!)

Comment: I think this is caused by the "fix" applied for this bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36049/bug-in-tag-stat-rendering

Comment: Jon Skeet renders all our css rules invalid

Comment: Well in that case, there's really no point in fixing it - he'll just mess it up again later.

Comment: almost dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts ;)

Comment: There seems to be inherent value in answering technical questions with simple easy to understand, generaly applicable answers.  Who would have thought that!

Answer (score 56):

I just fixed this ... will be deployed later today

It was a surprisingly easy fix:

```
UPDATE Users set Reputation = 0 where UserId = 22656
DELETE Votes where TargetUserId = 22656
```

Works like magic :)

Comment: Even Jon Skeet's *user ID* is higher than my reputation...

Comment: This fix won't last long ... unfortunately.

Comment: @waffles: This has to be reopened. Jon Skeet did it again!!

Comment: @LukasEder But he probably didn't _mean it_.

Comment: @TimPost: How do you know? He goes through lengths of challenging Stack Overflow. He's probably breaking other places of the layout time and again! ;-)

Answer (score 20):

Even with the recent switch to k notation, it's still on the verge of breaking again!

[image]

This is why we can't have nice things!

Comment: He did it again, now. Too many silver badges!

Comment: Badge counts should use 'k' notation too it seems.

Answer (score 18):

No, it's not broken. Jon Skeet is too big for one flair box.

But seriously, Stack Overflow is a self learning system. Each day it evolves into something more suitable for the current community. In the past, 9999 upvotes and 999 badges would have been enough. Today it isn't, so there's a need for a solution.

Possible solutions are:

- Ban any user that need too much space (or promote them to god status showing ∞ for each number).
- Use a smaller font for the flair or the questions/upvotes.
- Increase the amount of space for each entry.
- Use the K notation for answers and upvotes. (1k4 353   29k1 5k4)
- Rearrange the information. For example put the upvotes in smaller font below the number of answers.

The last two are probably the better solution.

Comment: here is an artistic impression of how it looks when the k notation is used everywhere. http://i.imgur.com/fATGI.png