# Imprecise (rounded) upvote counts on "topuser" page for a tag - can it be fixed?

Tags: feature-request, support, up-votes, top-users, tag-score

As of last night, the per-top-user "up-vote" counts that are over 1000 are displayed rounded to a hundred (e.g. user with 1105 will show "1.1k" instead). As an example, see [`Perl`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/topusers) tag.

I am guessing this has a reason (Jon Skeet's counts would be 5-6 characters wide, although 2 character savings doesn't seem like much win IMHO - [see this MSO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63867/jon-skeets-broken-the-c-tag-stats-page-formatting-on-so)), but this makes the exact # of up-votes unavailable. Is there any hidden switch/setting to show real non-rounded #s?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things most SO users don't realize is that a lot of stuff in the SO interface have the `title` attribute applied to them - this is one of the case. Hover over the rep for more than a second, and your browser should show it in the form of a tooltip:

[image]

Comment: WOW! I guess one can learn programming related stuff even from MSO! I didn't realize you can do `title` attribute on a `span` tag - I usually only try hover-over above images! Thanks!

Comment: @DVK The `title` attribute can usually be used for most HTML elements - for accessibility reasons