# Top Users Page Skeet-Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, reputation, design

Has this been reported before?

In the [C# tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers):

[image: Omg]

**Edit:** Seems like Mr. Skeet has been joined by Mr. Gravell by now...

[image: Omg2]

Comment: What is the report? Just the numbers running out of space? alas, this is a bit of a pathological edge-case (no offence, Jon). Maybe we should just take away Jon's badges... or display ∞

Comment: @Marc: Fortunately it'll be quite a while before it gets any worse. I can't see myself getting to 100 gold badges or 10K silver ones any time soon :)

Comment: @Jon of course, "1.3k" and "2.4k" might take a little less width - it is tempting...

Comment: @Marc - I'd say expressing badges like reputation (NNk) would work for a year or so.

Comment: Before the use of `k` for the rep. [Jon broke the C# top users list's formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63867/jon-skeets-broken-the-c-tag-stats-page-formatting-on-so). Time for a "multiple-offender" badge? :-)

Comment: You forgot the Jon Skeet tag! ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet: How long did you have in mind for *"any time soon"*? :)

Comment: @H.B.: Yes, there did seem to be a bit of a rush of gold badges for some reason. 10K silver is still a long way off though :)