# One badge to rule them all

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request

The elves from Eerie lake forge one badge to contain all, for ever until the Dark Tower falls.

After seeing [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101211/top-users-page-skeet-overflow), it was obvious some serious action should be taken rapidly. Therefore, the following proposal.

When any user reaches 2<sup>10</sup> badges of one kind (bronze most likely), their badge score (all their badges) is replaced by a Platinum badge. **When anyone clicks on the Platinum badge, he/she sees the real count of Gold, Silver and Bronze badges**. This is the KiloMan badge (or Jon Skeet Badge as per Donal's request).

When any user reaches 2<sup>20</sup> reputation points, he/she gets the MegaMan Platinum badge.

People can get more than one KiloMan or MegaMan badge, just like any other badge.

**Edit:** Instead of hiding the badges of top scorers, they could be rendered vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: **Why?** Each individual badge *means* something. Consolidating them all into one mega-badge *loses* that meaning.

Comment: **Because**: look at the **bold** section of the proposal. Nothing is lost.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Meh. Unless 2<sup>10</sup> MegaMan badges get you the Jon Skeet badge. That would be awesome.

Comment: I vote for that

Comment: I'll drink to that